# Regex match rss <item> content where word not in <link>?

Tags: php, regex

Are "regexing" out content of an rss's `<item>(...)</item>`s but don't want the matches to contain '`europe`' inside the `<link>...</link>` element.

For example:

**OK:**

```
<item>
    <title>The title</title>
    <link>//website-india.com/the-title</link>
    <description>The description</description>
</item>
```

**NOT OK:**

```
<item>
    <title>The title</title>
    <link>//website-europe.com/the-title</link>
    <description>The description</description>
</item>
```

Have tried a several different ways. Right now my regex is

```
<item>(.*<link>.*(?!europe).*</link>.*)</item>
```

witch of course doesn't work. But have tried to replace the `.*` to `(?!item)` as well but without success.

Anyone know how to do in this case?

**Edit:**

Just thought this would work but no. It just ignores the whole not-statement and outputs all items:

```
<item>(((?!item)*).*?<link>[^<]*(?!europe)[^<]*</link>((?!item)*).*?)</item>
```

**Edit 2:**

This seems to work. Will try it out more before I consider it a correct answer:

```
<item>(((?!item).)*<link>((?!europe).)*</link>((?!item).)*)</item>
```

Comment: Anyone that can explain why this question is such bad?

Comment: Your question doesn't look all that bad to me, but "doesn't work" isn't a very good problem statement. What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: Aha, of course. Thanks for explaining the problem with the question. Much easier to know how to improve then. And with "doesn't work" I meant it returned a html string containing a lot of items code and both with and without 'europe'. But I have solved the question myself now. Just succeeded. Will update the question with the solution.

Comment: Oh no. Seems to actually not work...if there is an item before with europe it includes that...

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code :

```
preg_match_all('~<item>.*<link>((?:(?!europ).)+)</link>.*</item>~s', $rss, $out);
```